# Attaching Debugger To Dynamic Process

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In netbeans there is a property called attach debugger where you can attach debugger to the running application, similarly I assume that there should be some functionality in Visual Studio 2010 too.I couldn't figure out.Anyone has any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is such option in Debug menu - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3s68z0b3.aspx

Comment: Even I have found it, but there we have to select a process.I am trying to debug a java file, I couldn't find that file in the list of processes.Have you ever tried this?????

Comment: your java file should be run as one of processes typically  it is java.exe . You may try attach to each java.exe process one by one and examine Modules window. In Modules window you may see all libraries loaded along with information about debug symbols loaded or not.

Comment: all java programs run in the context of a JVM host, called java.exe